# Can't create Tasks inside task folder using ews in exchange online

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to create the tasks using ews but it is giving ErrorInvalidIdMalformed error.

I have already tried using wellknownfolders name and with task folder id but I am not able to create task

```
email_id = "xyz@pqr.onmicrosoft.com"
folder_id = "tasks"
# or folder_id="id of some task folder"

RestoreTASK = b'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
    <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
      <t:ConnectingSID>
        %s
      </t:ConnectingSID>
    </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<CreateItem
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
    MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
    <SavedItemFolderId>
        <t:FolderId Id="%s"/>
    </SavedItemFolderId>
    <Items>
        <t:Task>
            <t:Subject>My task EWS</t:Subject>
            <t:DueDate>2006-10-26T21:32:52</t:DueDate>
            <t:Status>NotStarted</t:Status>
        </t:Task>
    </Items>
  </CreateItem>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>''' % (email_id, folder_id)

ews_api_url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx'
response = requests.post(url=ews_api_url, headers = headers,
```

data=RestoreTASK)

So do I need to make changes in my soap request because folder id that I am specifing manually is correct.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the folderId is wrong so how do you know its correct ? How did you retrieve the FolderId in the first place ? eg a simple test of you XML with DistinguishedFolderId works fine

```html
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
 </soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<CreateItem
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
    MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
    <SavedItemFolderId>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="tasks"/>
    </SavedItemFolderId>
    <Items>
        <t:Task>
            <t:Subject>My task EWS</t:Subject>
            <t:DueDate>2006-10-26T21:32:52</t:DueDate>
            <t:Status>NotStarted</t:Status>
        </t:Task>
    </Items>
  </CreateItem>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help, Thanks Glen.

Comment: I got this id using https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net. I authenticated myself using username/password and got the oauth token and fired the rest api like ... me/taskfolders. So here we can find the folder id with all task foldes with their display name. 
Now it is working fine with folder id but How CAN I CREATE ATTACHMENT with task ?

Comment: oauthplay.azurewebsites.net. is using REST the REST id's are different from EWS (they are URI safe). If you want to use REST then use REST but don't mix the two (. If you want an application to get EWSIds use the EWSeditor or just use EWS requests to get the I'ds you should never use hardcorded id's in your code.

Comment: use the CreateAttachment operation. A task is just like Email,Contact,Appointment the operation is the same.

Comment: We back up user's mailbox using rest api and we restore it using ews in seprate folder in user's mailbox where first we create folder using ews and then using these returned folder id's from ews, we create data using soap request.

Comment: Now, situation is , we only want to store the backed up in same user's folder.
Ex. user has Inbox-A and he has some mails in A. He deleted some mails. Now I want to restore the data in same A folder (without creating a new A folder)

Comment: We back up user's mailbox using rest api and we restore it using ews ? Why ? if you can backup it with REST then restore it with REST there is no need to use EWS. You second question logically makes no sense you want to restore to folder call A but you don't want to create it if it doesn't exist that's impossible if it does exist the you need to find the Id of the folder first then you an issue whatever request against that folder? . It just sounds to me like you need to search for the folder first if its doesn't exist then create it (or whatever logic you want).

Comment: If A folder exists in user's mailbox, then use the same folder (this is where problem is coming because I am using the folderId  to restore message inside it that I fetched using rest api). Is there a way where I can fetch folderId after giving folder name using EWS so that I can use this folderId to restore message.
But in case If folder is not there, then I create that folder and I am able to restore data in that folder (because this here I use CreateItem class and store the newly created folderId).